# Resetting varchar table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

While importing an old database into SQL Server I managed to give thousands of people the same first and last name (brilliant me). Is there a script to run to make the first name column for everyone blank or say `First Name`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try  `update [tablename] set [firstname] = ''`